# Xcode 11.3.1 - Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, archive

Everything in my app was fine before 26th april.

But my code sign certificate has expired in 27th april and I'm getting this issue.

I'm getting this error at the end of archive in Xcode. and the archive is failed.

My Xcode version is 11.3.1.
I've done below steps to solve this issue:-

1. I've removed pod and reinstall.
2. have **lock and unlock the login from keychain certificate**.
3. have created a new certificate which is valid for another year.

but still my issue is not solving.
Please suggest me the solution if anybody have faced similar type of issue.

Comment: Did you go to the XCode preferences-> Accounts and ensure that you are logged in with the correct AppleId? Then click Manage Certificates and ensure your current active certficate is in the list? If not the + button on the left to add it. Then in the main XCode window, select the project on the far left, then the Target and in Signing & Capabilities ensure the Signing Certificate is set to the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I lack some information, but I can give the following tips:

- Make sure you have the new certificate on the same machine and remove the old one from the keychain.
- Make sure you've regenerated the provisioning profiles with the new certificate if you've done that before. Also make sure you've downloaded and installed the new ones.
- (!) Make sure you have the new Apple Worldwide certificate on the machine - https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/

If the above doesn't work, Clean Build Folder, close the project, quit Xcode, reopen the project.

Comment: now archive is done successfully after adding Apple Worldwide certificate. But now I'm getting "XXXX has apple distribution certificates but their private keys are not installed". what to do now???